# Entity Framework Database-First Collections

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, ef-database-first, database-first

Ok, so I have myself a generated class called Vault.CS which was generated from my database table "Kingdoms". "Kingdoms" is seperated into 3 conceptual models called "Kingdom", "Army, "Vault". Vault is a conceptual model that refers to the ItemSlot1-ItemSlot16 columns each of these fields is a integer.

My question is how could I refer to these 16 fields as a collection in my extended class? For example, if I want to add an item to a "Vault" it should find the first empty(0 or null) slot in slots 1-16 then add the integer that cooresponds to a particular item into that field. I was doing some reading on complex classes but did not read anything about being able to sort through a set of properties in this way. Any ideas?

Comment: Any codes? sample? example...?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your idea clearly, however I think that you need something like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(VaultAttribs))]
public partial class Vault
{
    public void Add(int item)
    {
        var v = db.Vaults.FirstOrDefault();
        var ps = v.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < ps.Lenght; i++)
            if (ps[i].Equals(null))
            {
                ps[i].SetValue(v, item, null);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
    }
}

public class VaultAttribs
{        
    // Vault attribs...
}
```

Comment: Ok, great. That is exactly what I was looking for Amin. Basically the problem for me was that I had 16 properties in the generated Vault.cs class file. Initially what I was attempting to do was make some sort of collection( I went with dictionary ) to store those properties so that later I could iterate over them. I am new to reflection but your reply actually hits the nail on the head and now I've gotten rid of the initial collection notion and can use reflection to iterate over the properties. I've adapted this almost line for line, except that persistence is contained in a parent class.

Comment: I did however in my tinkering get the collection idea to work[almost] in that I got all the properties into a <int, int?> Dictionary and initialized the dictionary with the cooresponding properties such as { 1, ItemSlot1 }, etc. However, the problem I ran into after all of that is that I could not directly modify the values, perhaps I was doing it wrong(with the = assignment operator). Now I know that you have to use the .SetValues() method. Hope this helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The class generated should be partial.
[partial class help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Which means you add extra properties and methods without touching the generated class part.

Comment: Indeed the generated class is a partial class. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can use the properties in the class as a collection. I'd like to be able to for example, add an item to a vault which will place the item's cooresponding identifying number into the first available slot. Say ItemSlot1 = 3, ItemSlot2 = 2, ItemSlot3 = 11, and the rest are null, I could then say Vault.Add(9); which would determine if any slots are available, then because ItemSlot4 is null it would assign it to that slot. Does this make sense?

Comment: I dont understand the use case no.  But creating a new File that represents the second half of the partial class and exposes a  ICollection<Vault> {get;set;} . is simple.   If it is NOT virtual EF wont try and make a foreign key with it. you cant refer to poco.field1 etc in the partial class. Sounds the question has morphed into how to deal with a collection or array of 16 items ? Perhaps explain the question better.